# Juniper SSG-5 different vlans authentication

Tags: authentication, vlan, juniper, ssg5

In my network infrastructur I have 2 companies right now. Every company has it own vlan.

For example:

Company A 192.168.100.0/24

Company B 192.168.101.0/24

I want to use a shared vlan for all Companies: 192.168.0.0/24
In this shared network everyone has access to Internet and to our printer. This is no problem for me.

However, I want to give them the opportunity to connect to their own vlan with an authentication.
For this I want to use my firewall Juniper SSG5 and a MS Radius server. I have no switch which supports 802.1X.

Which way is the best way to do this?

Thanks for help in advanced!